# parsing decimals into a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, decimal

```
<input value="123" />
<span></span>

$('input').change(function (){
    var val = $(this).val().toFixed(2);
    $('span').text(val);
});
```

I have tried the code above but can't seem to get the decimal on the `text()` is just shows as 123. This is my first time experimentind with `toFixed()`

just in case `toFixed()` is a `js` native method not a `jquery`

Comment: Is spam a typo here or in your code?

Comment: @jgauffin yes I noticed it as well but thnx :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`toFixed` is a method that you would call on a number, not on a string. You need to parse the string to a number:

```
var val = parseFloat($(this).val(), 10).toFixed(2);
```

Live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/QrW5C/

Comment: ok this works how ever the problem was at `$('span').val( val | 0 );` which I always thought `|` is like a `or` statement replaced `val|0` with `val?val:0` to avoid the `NaN` values

Comment: @Val: It should be `val || 0`. `|` is bitwise OR. `||` is logical OR.

Comment: two birds with one stone lol :) by birds i mean questions answered :) thnx mate

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error console. You should see something like:

```
TypeError: Object 123 has no method 'toFixed'
```

Strings don't have the `toFixed()` method. Only numbers have. Convert the value to a number first (e.g. by prepending `+`):

```
var val = (+$(this).val()).toFixed(2);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YHw92/)

Comment: my fault should have mentioned this... on console.log(); looks fine with two decimals but not on the `span` tag

Comment: @Val: What exactly do you mean? `$(this).val().toFixed(2);` definitely does not work. The above should work: http://jsfiddle.net/YHw92/

Comment: no i meant console.log(val) is cool it works, $('span').text(val); does not

Comment: @Val: Then there is some other error in your actual code. As you can see in the example, it works.

Comment: look at the @darins  comments under his answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it:

```
var NumericValue = parseFloat($(this).val())
var val = NumericValue .toFixed(2);
```

info here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1013-Javascript-Number-toFixed-Method.htm

also:

```
<span></spam> (?)
```

Comment: why so critical about the `m` lol you know it's next to n and they look similar easy `typo` :)

Comment: no worries, just wasnt sure. Probably was a bit rude of me to put it as a code block. appologies :)